# Dealing with NULL Dates within a Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query I'm putting together to try and show all the values between 28 and 29 Nov and also those that have a TimeIn value between those dates but a NULL value for TimeOut.

```
    SELECT  
        TimeIn,
        TimeOut
    FROM
        Movement VM
    WHERE 
        Area  = 1 AND
        ((
        VM.TimeIn >= '28 Nov 2016' AND 
        VM.TimeOut < DATEADD (d,1,'29 Nov 2016' ) OR VM.TimeOut IS NULL) )
        order by timein
```

These are the results I get:

```
**TimeIn                  TimeOut**

2016-11-10 01:16:04.807 NULL

2016-11-10 01:18:48.900 NULL

2016-11-10 01:28:10.350 NULL

2016-11-10 01:31:28.693 NULL

2016-11-13 16:22:45.273 NULL

2016-11-14 22:18:06.210 NULL

2016-11-18 23:05:15.753 NULL

2016-11-19 00:22:39.810 NULL

2016-11-19 00:36:44.570 NULL

2016-11-19 00:40:42.507 NULL

2016-11-19 00:42:14.463 NULL

2016-11-19 00:45:05.860 NULL

2016-11-20 22:35:10.830 NULL

2016-11-20 22:41:27.383 NULL

2016-11-20 23:22:57.177 NULL

2016-11-21 02:17:36.053 NULL

2016-11-28 02:13:05.060 2016-11-28 02:13:05.060

2016-11-29 00:01:14.910 2016-11-29 00:01:14.910

2016-11-29 00:04:29.827 2016-11-29 00:04:29.827

2016-11-29 00:07:14.840 2016-11-29 00:07:14.840

2016-11-29 00:09:52.807 2016-11-29 00:09:52.807

2016-11-29 00:13:10.217 2016-11-29 00:13:10.217

2016-11-29 00:15:33.587 2016-11-29 00:15:33.587

2016-11-29 00:25:12.573 2016-11-29 00:25:12.573

2016-11-29 02:47:41.570 NULL

2016-11-29 12:31:50.503 2016-11-29 12:31:50.503

2016-11-29 12:39:01.483 2016-11-29 12:39:01.483

2016-11-29 13:03:43.477 2016-11-29 13:04:43.663

2016-11-30 01:43:05.487 NULL

2016-11-30 01:44:05.480 NULL

2016-11-30 01:51:22.277 NULL

2016-11-30 01:55:24.000 NULL

2016-11-30 01:57:44.620 NULL

2016-11-30 02:00:04.150 NULL

2016-11-30 02:16:05.823 NULL

2016-11-30 15:57:35.517 NULL

2016-12-02 00:28:22.487 NULL

2016-12-02 01:07:07.303 NULL

2016-12-09 02:18:40.897 NULL

but I only want to return the below. How can I get my syntax in the correct method?



 **TimeIn                  TimeOut**

    2016-11-28 02:13:05.060 2016-11-28 02:13:05.060

    2016-11-29 00:01:14.910 2016-11-29 00:01:14.910

    2016-11-29 00:04:29.827 2016-11-29 00:04:29.827

    2016-11-29 00:07:14.840 2016-11-29 00:07:14.840

    2016-11-29 00:09:52.807 2016-11-29 00:09:52.807

    2016-11-29 00:13:10.217 2016-11-29 00:13:10.217

    2016-11-29 00:15:33.587 2016-11-29 00:15:33.587

    2016-11-29 00:25:12.573 2016-11-29 00:25:12.573

    2016-11-29 02:47:41.570 NULL

    2016-11-29 12:31:50.503 2016-11-29 12:31:50.503

    2016-11-29 12:39:01.483 2016-11-29 12:39:01.483

    2016-11-29 13:03:43.477 2016-11-29 13:04:43.663
```

Comment: `'28 Nov 2016'` is _not_ a valid date string, which means you are not comparing dates, you're comparing _strings_.  Use this format instead: `'2016-11-28'`

Comment: I guess, you are expecting to merge the time in and out. Is it so?

Comment: Tim, SQL server will perform an implicit conversion so it is valid.

Comment: @TJB I did not know this, thanks.  By the way, we have the same initials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the top and not the bottom is due to your `OR` syntax.  Your `OR` needs to be in the same parentheses as your `ValidTo` limitation

i.e. `(validTo > '29 Nov 2016' OR null)` and not `(validTo > '29 Nov 2016') OR NULL`.  Having `NULL` outside returns every single row that has a `NULL` in that column.

So your syntax needs to be (edited):

```
    SELECT TimeIn
    ,[TimeOut]
FROM Movement VM
WHERE Area = 1
    AND CAST(VM.TimeIn AS DATE) BETWEEN '28 Nov 2016' AND '29 Nov 2016'
            AND (
                CAST(VM.TimeOut AS DATE) <= '29 Nov 2016'
                OR VM.TimeOut IS NULL
                )
ORDER BY timein
```

Comment: That's right, which is the struggle to get it included correctly.

Comment: I still think you should phrase your date strings as `'2016-11-29'` because it will allow the query to be ported more easily to another database.

Comment: I have provided the correct solution for you James.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work @TJB . Your query still returns those values after 29th Nov when it shouldn't. These values 2016-11-30 01:43:05.487 NULL

2016-11-30 01:44:05.480 NULL

2016-11-30 01:51:22.277 NULL

2016-11-30 01:55:24.000 NULL

2016-11-30 01:57:44.620 NULL

2016-11-30 02:00:04.150 NULL

2016-11-30 02:16:05.823 NULL

2016-11-30 15:57:35.517 NULL

2016-12-02 00:28:22.487 NULL

2016-12-02 01:07:07.303 NULL

2016-12-09 02:18:40.897 NULL

Comment: OK, I didn't realise you didn't want the TimeIns to not exceed the 29th, I have amended the query, please try again.

Comment: Thanks @TJB appreciate that